# cyclic reference problem in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

While learning hibernate i came across a situation where it seems Hibernate is having cyclic reference and i am clueless how to come through this situation. i have two classes a parent

```
private String uuid;
private String name;
private Set<ChildClass> childclass=new HashSet<ChildClass>();
```

and here is the mapping file for the same

```
<property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="255" />
    <set name="childclass" table="Parent_Child" lazy="extra"
        cascade="save-update">
        <key column="parent_id" />
        <many-to-many class="com.test.child.ChildClass" column="child_id"/>
    </set>
```

for child entries are as follows

```
private String name;
private Set<ParentClass> parent=new HashSet<ParentClass>();
private String child_id;

<property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="255" />
    <set name="parent" table="Parent_Child" inverse="true" lazy="extra"
        cascade="save-update">
        <key column="child_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="com.test.parent.ParentClass" column="PARENT_ID"/>
    </set>
```

when i tried something like this in my main code

```
tx1.begin();
String query="from ParentClass as pc";
Query query1=session1.createQuery(query);
List list= query1.list();
```

now here lies the real problem when ever i will try to iterate the list with iterator method or any collection method it goes in to infinite loop like parent have reference to child and again child have reference to parent

in my upcoming assignment i have a parent class having so many collection references to child classes all have many-to- one and one-to-many relation.

So it seems that in that condition when ever i will try to fetch child from the parent entity like

```
parent.getChild().iterator()
```

it will run in to circular reference.
Please suggest me how to avoid this or correct me if i am on wrong track

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are having a situation like this:

```
ID | name | parent
1  | P1   | null
2  | P2   | P4
3  | P3   | P2
4  | P4   | P2
```

In this case, you have a cyclic reference, for IDs 2 and 4. This is a "classical" problem for linked lists, and there are several techniques (algorithms) to detect this. You may want to do some research on the topic, as it's really not suitable for a stackoverflow answer ;-)

But I would first assess if the business requirement really mandates to have a structure with the possibility of a cyclic dependency. If it doesn't, then you can put a "check" in your "addChild()" or "setParent()" method, to verify if the parent/child creates a cyclic dependency. The simple solution is to always require a "parent = null" for the top-level parent record.